# Capistrano before/after hooks, use_sudo, something not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have the below config in my `deploy.rb`

```
before("deploy:cleanup") { set :use_sudo, true }
  after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
after("deploy:cleanup") { set :use_sudo, false }
```

This is because some other factor in my setup creates files with a different user and I need to be able to clean them up. Elsewhere, I set it to `false` default.

The problem is, when I run `deploy`, I am not able to run `cleanup`, I am getting permissions errors, and I see the command generated as

```
ls -1dt /u/apps/MYAPP/releases/* | tail -n +6 |  xargs rm -rf
```

However, if i run `deploy:cleanup` directly it works just fine with the below command.

```
sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ls -1dt /u/apps/netprice/releases/* | tail -n +6 | sudo -p 'sudo password: ' xargs rm -rf
```

I am not sure if this is as expected, and I am understanding capistrano wrong, and if there is a cleaner (:P) way to achieve this?

I am using Rails 3.2 and capistrano 2.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because you are trying to set the wrong configuration key. The `deploy:cleanup` task uses internally the `try_sudo` method. If you see the [source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.4/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L163) of that method you will notice that it executes the command based on the contents of `run_method` key instead of `use_sudo`.

This means that if you change your code to `set :run_method, :sudo` (and then back to `:run`) you should get what you need.

As a side note, the `use_sudo` key is actually [used internally](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.4/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L68) when capistrano boots to set the appropriate value to `run_method`

Comment: Curious so `use_sudo` is used in initialization stage and cannot, effectively, be changed after that? Curious... Am using the `run_method` key now, hope the issue does not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use Unix permission groups: make both users members of the same permission group and grant delete action to group members (+w). Then your 'deploy user' will be able to delete files created by your other user.